# Spring Boot global controller advice is not loaded in Spring Context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a controller to receive POST requests and return a JSON output. An exception handler which was implemented inside the controller class worked fine.

I have tried to add Global exception handling with `@ControllerAdvice` annotation, but this doesn't work in my solution. I don't think the global exception handler class is being loaded.

Below is my controller class:

```
package hello;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/v1")
public class MyController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/saveEmployee", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
  @ResponseBody
  public String saveEmployee(@Valid @RequestBody Employee employee) {
    return "{ \"name\":\"" + employee.getEmail() + "\"}";
  }
}
```

Below is Global exception handler class:

```
package util;

@ControllerAdvice
public class MyControllerAdvice {

  @ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
  // @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
  @ResponseBody
  public String processValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException ex) {
    BindingResult result = ex.getBindingResult();
    FieldError fieldError = result.getFieldError();
    String code = fieldError.getCode();
    String field = fieldError.getField();
    String message = fieldError.getDefaultMessage();
    message = "{ \"Code\":\"" + code + "\",\"field\":\"" + field + "\",\"Message\":\"" + message + "\"}";
    return message;
  }
}
```

Below are my configurations:

```
package hello;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:messages");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator() {
        LocalValidatorFactoryBean bean = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        bean.setValidationMessageSource(messageSource());
        return bean;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Spring boot version : 2.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: This is what i receive in invalid parameter passing to the controller  "[nio-8080-exec-2] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException: Validation failed for argument at index 0 in method:"@Piotr Rogowski

Comment: Can you post your Spring configuration for the said controllers? I'm seeing that the controller is in a package called `hello` whereas the exception handler in a package called `util`. My first though is that you're not bringing the exception handler into context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think the problem you have here is exactly what you identified. The `MyControllerAdvice` class isn't being loaded. From the code you posted, I'm inferring that your project structure looks something like:

```
src
  main
    java
      hello
        Application.java
        MyController.java
      util
        MyControllerAdvice.java
```

Because you have the `SpringBootApplication` annotation on your `Application` class, Spring Boot uses that as its starting point for creating beans, and it looks for classes annotated with things like `@Controller` and `@ControllerAdvice` (among others) to add to its context.

There are many different ways to configure that, but the simplest if you're starting out or working with a relatively small project, will be to restructure it to fit Spring's recommendation here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-structuring-your-code.html

That page is very short and worth reading to get the background, but the essence is that you want your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class in the same package or a parent package as all the classes you want Spring to manage, the page above gives the following example:

```
com
 +- example
   +- myapplication
     +- Application.java
     |
     +- customer
     | +- Customer.java
     | +- CustomerController.java
     | +- CustomerService.java
     | +- CustomerRepository.java
     |
     +- order
       +- Order.java
       +- OrderController.java
       +- OrderService.java
       +- OrderRepository.java
```

So, in your case, this would mean either moving the `util` package under `hello`, like:

```
src
  main
    java
      hello
        Application.java
        MyController.java
        util
          MyControllerAdvice.java
```

Or creating a parent package for both `hello` and `util` and moving `Application` up to that package, like:

```
src
  main
    java
      example
        Application.java
        hello
          MyController.java
        util
          MyControllerAdvice.java
```

Comment: Yes. This works. I've re structured the entire project.Now the Spring boot has added @ControllerAdvice to the context. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this: `@ControllerAdvice("hello")`

According to the documentation of `ControllerAdvice`:

> Controllers that belong to those base packages or sub-packages thereof will be included, e.g.: @ControllerAdvice(basePackages="org.my.pkg") or @ControllerAdvice(basePackages={"org.my.pkg", "org.my.other.pkg"}).
>   value is an alias for this attribute, simply allowing for more concise use of the annotation.
>   Also consider using basePackageClasses() as a type-safe alternative to String-based package names.

Comment: I've already tried this. But no difference.What i observe is "DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved exception caused by Handler execution: org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException:"@Hank

Comment: Try put `MyControllerAdvice` to the same package of `MyController`. I could reproduce your problem and fix it by my solution, both.

Comment: Yes. I just tried the same as you mentioned and that worked. Thanks. But do you identify any reason to not to work MyControllerAdvice in a different package ? @Hank

Comment: @DaveyDaveDave's answer explains my point. Spring use the package of `@SpringBootApplication` class as default root package and scan Beans/Configurations under that root package. That's why your `@ControllerAdvice` is not found by Spring at the beginning :). But please also note that, just pulling `@SpringBootApplication` to upper level is not enough, `@ControllerAdvice` effects the same package (and sub packages) of `@Controller` only by default, except you config `basePackages` correctly.

Comment: Yes. It was a great advice. I configured the base package correctly and sorted the issue.@Hank

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it throws MethodArgumentNotValidException? Make the default handler like this

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {Exception.class})
public ResponseEntity<Object> exception(Exception exception) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(exception, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
}
```

Comment: No. This doesn't work. Yes i'm sure that it it fires a MethodArgumentNotValidException @GerNik

Comment: This helped me to get insights if it's not being caught by another handler.